# Compute the Carmichael function

Tags: code-golf, math, number, number-theory, primes

### Task description

In number theory, the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) ***λ*** takes a positive integer **n** and returns the least positive integer **k** so that the **k**-th power of each integer [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) to **n** equals 1 modulo **n**.

Given a positive integer **n**, your solution must compute ***λ*(n)**. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Your program should theoretically work for arbitrarily large inputs, but doesn’t need to be efficient.

### Tips

The sequence of all ***λ*(n)** is [OEIS A002322](https://oeis.org/A002322).

An ungolfed Python implementation would look like

```
from fractions import gcd

def carmichael(n):
    coprimes = [x for x in range(1, n) if gcd(x, n) == 1]
    k = 1
    while not all(pow(x, k, n) == 1 for x in coprimes):
        k += 1
    return k
```

(In Python, `pow(A, B, C)` efficiently computes `pow(A, B) % C`.)

### Test cases

```
Input    Output
1        1
2        1
3        2
10       4
35       12
101      100
530      52
3010     84
6511     3056
10000    500
```

Comment: What does *theoretically* mean here? Can I assume that the input **n** fits in a 16-bit integer? Can I assume that **n^λ(n)** fits in a double?

Comment: Yes and yes, I’d say. As in, the *theoretically* includes *pretend your native types are arbitrarily precise and large* (I thought that was consensus, but I’m not sure).

Answer (score 49):

### Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
CarmichaelLambda
```

Well...

Comment: ..... really.  ._.

Comment: I don't like u mathematica

Comment: @acrolith yeah '-'

Answer (score 28):

## Python, <s>76</s> <s>73</s> 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:1-any(a**-~k*~-a**k%n for a in range(n))or-~f(n,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FY7BDoMgEETP5Sv2QgQLjdTSg4n9F1q1IepigB68@OuW3WQzuy@ZyZxTv7j1PThANfemM9rhLlxd62OuD12OmSNMIYIDjxAdfkeBUoaoj0kUz9XI069biBnSnljZWxpzHD@/mHzAxa8@C9OUkQwYBSEFCaPgrqBVYJoilrQg29LXEHtaY4iSs2OXLXrMouJ2AP0C/hgq4FAKwER15PkH)

A further byte could be saved by returning *True* instead of **1**.

#### Alternative implementation

Using the same approach, there is also the following implementation by @feersum which doesn't use list comprehensions.

```python
f=lambda n,k=1,a=1:a/n or(a**-~k*~-a**k%n<1)*f(n,k,a+1)or-~f(n,k+1)
```

Note that this implementation requires **O(n<sup>λ(n)</sup>)** time. Efficiency could be improved dramatically while actually *decreasing* score to **66 bytes**, but the function would return *True* for input **2**.

```python
f=lambda n,k=1,a=1:a/n or~-a**k*a**-~k%n<1==f(n,k,a+1)or-~f(n,k+1)
```

### Background

#### Definitions and notation

All employed variables will denote integers; **n**, **k**, and **α** will denote *positive* integers; and **p** will denote a positive *prime*.

**a | b** if **b** is divisible by **a**, i.e., if there is **q** such that **b = qa**.

**a ≡ b (*mod* m)** if **a** and **b** have the same residue modulo **m**, i.e., if **m | a - b**.

**λ(n)** is the smallest **k** such that **a<sup>k</sup> ≡ 1 (*mod* n)** – i.e., such that **n | a<sup>k</sup> - 1** – for all **a** that are coprime to **n**.

**f(n)** is the smallest **k** such that **a<sup>2k+1</sup> ≡ a<sup>k+1</sup> (*mod* n)** – i.e., such that **n | a<sup>k+1</sup>(a<sup>k</sup> - 1)** – for all **a**.

#### λ(n) ≤ f(n)

Fix **n** and let **a** be coprime to **n**.

By the definition of **f**, **n | a<sup>f(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>f(n)</sup> - 1)**. Since **a** and **n** do not have a common prime factor, neither do **a<sup>f(n)+1</sup>** and **n**, which implies that **n | a<sup>f(n)</sup> - 1**.

Since **λ(n)** is the smallest integer **k** such that **n | a<sup>k</sup> - 1** for all integers **a** that are coprime to **n**, it follows that **λ(n) ≤ f(n)**.

#### λ(n) = f(n)

Since we've already established the inequality **λ(n) ≤ f(n)**, it is sufficient to verify that **k = λ(n)** satisfies the condition that defines **f**, i.e., that **n | a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1)** for all **a**. For this purpose, we'll establish that **p<sup>α</sup> | a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1)** whenever **p<sup>α</sup> | n**.

**λ(k) | λ(n)** whenever **k | n** ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Divisibility)), so **(a<sup>λ(k)</sup> - 1)(a<sup>λ(n)-λ(k)</sup> + a<sup>λ(n)-2λ(k)</sup> + ⋯ + a<sup>λ(k)</sup> + 1) = a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1** and, therefore, **a<sup>λ(k)</sup> - 1 | a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1 | a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1)**.

If **a** and **p<sup>α</sup>** are coprime, by the definition of **λ** and the above, **p<sup>α</sup> | a<sup>λ(p<sup>α</sup>)</sup> - 1 | a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1)** follows, as desired.

If **a = 0**, then **a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1) = 0**, which is divisible by all integers.

Finally, we must consider the case where **a** and **p<sup>α</sup>** have a common prime factor. Since **p** is prime, this implies that **p | a**. [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Carmichael.27s_theorem) establishes that **λ(p<sup>α</sup>) = (p - 1)p<sup>α - 1</sup>** if **p > 2** or **α < 3** and that **λ(p<sup>α</sup>) = p<sup>α - 2</sup>** otherwise. In all cases, **λ(p<sup>α</sup>) ≥ p<sup>α - 2</sup> ≥ 2<sup>α - 2</sup> > α - 2**.

Therefore, **λ(n) + 1 ≥ λ(p<sup>α</sup>) + 1 > α - 1**, so **λ(n) + 1 ≥ α** and **p<sup>α</sup> | p<sup>λ(n)+1</sup> | a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup> | a<sup>λ(n)+1</sup>(a<sup>λ(n)</sup> - 1)**. This completes the proof.

### How it works

While the definitions of **f(n)** and **λ(n)** consider all possible values of **a**, it is sufficient to test those that lie in **[0, ..., n - 1]**.

When **f(n, k)** is called, it computes **a<sup>k+1</sup>(a<sup>k</sup> - 1) % n** for all values of **a** in that range, which is **0** if and only if **n | a<sup>k+1</sup>(a<sup>k</sup> - 1)**.

If all computed residues are zero, **k = λ(n)** and `any` returns *False*, so **f(n, k)** returns **1**.

On the other hand, while **k < λ(n)**, `1-any(...)` will return **0**, so **f** is called recursively with an incremented value of **k**. The leading `-~` increments the return value of **f(n, k + 1)**, so we add **1** to **f(n, λ(n)) = 1** once for every integer in **[1, ..., λ(n) - 1]**. The final result is thus **λ(n)**.

Comment: You can save at least 4 with recursion instead of a list comprehension: `f=lambda n,k=1,a=1:a/n or(a**k*~-a**k%n<1)*f(n,k,a+2-n%2)or-~f(n,k+1)` (Add back one byte if you don't like it to take n**λ(n) time).

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime, I found an improvement to my algorithm that seems to nullify the benefit of recursing instead of using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 14):

## Mathematica without built-in, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for finding an error, then saving me the bytes it took to fix it!*

*Thanks to miles for saving 1 byte! (which seemed like 2 to me)*

Built-ins are totally fine ... but for those who want to implement it without using brute force, here's a formula for the Carmichael function:

```
LCM@@(EulerPhi[#^#2]/If[#==2<#2,2,1]&@@@FactorInteger@#)&
```

If p is a prime, the Carmichael function λ(p^r) equals φ(p^r) = (p-1)*p^(r-1)—*except* when p=2 and r≥3, in which case it's half that, namely 2^(r-2).

And if the prime-power factorization of n equals p1^r1 * p2^r2 * ..., then λ(n) equals the least common multiple of { λ(p1^r1), λ(p2^r2), ...}.

Runtime is one instant more than factoring the integer in the first place.

Comment: You can use `EulerPhi` to get `LCM@@(EulerPhi[#^#2]/If[#==2<#2,2,1]&@@@FactorInteger@#)&` for 57 bytes.

Comment: @miles nicely spotted! I count 56 bytes, can you check?

Comment: Yeah, it's 57 [bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#LCM@@(EulerPhi[#^#2]/If[#==2<#2,2,1]&@@@FactorInteger@#)&).

Comment: clearly I even try to golf my counting.... :/

Answer (score 12):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 246 bytes

```
Fun<Ap<Fun<If<Eq<A<2>,T>,A<1>,And<Eq<Ap<Fun<If<A<1>,Ap<A<0>,Rem<A<2>,A<1>>,A<1>>,A<2>>>,A<1,1>,A<2>>,T>,Sub<Ap<Fun<Rem<If<A<1>,Mul<A<2,1>,Ap<A<0>,Sub<A<1>,T>>>,T>,A<1,2>>>,A<1>>,T>>,Ap<A<0>,Add<A<1>,T>,A<1,1>>,Ap<A<0>,A<1>,Sub<A<2>,T>>>>,T,A<1>>>
```

An unnamed function (not that there are named functions).

This is a forgotten esolang of mine which is interpreted by a C++ compiler instantiating templates. With the default max template depth of `g++`, it can do λ(35), but it can't do λ(101) (the lazy evaluation makes things worse).

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```hs
f n=[k|k<-[1..],and[mod(m^k)n<2|m<-[1..n],gcd m n<2]]!!0
```

Answer (score 9):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
Æc
```

[Thank you for the builtin, @Lynn](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/commit/6136ca6a64b3247e2de53587cc4305d0255f7451)

Comment: ............. ._.

Comment: I never understand the point of implementing such ridiculously specific built-ins.

Comment: This is *almost* an addition to the language specifically made for this challenge. Commit by Lynn 2 days ago, challenge by @Lynn today

Comment: @edc65 Not to mention that this built-in is pretty much useless outside this challenge and derivatives of it.

Comment: Well, the Carmichael function is important in number theory (as the currently top answer reflects), so I wouldn't call it useless.

Comment: @Fatalize: Do you have 65536 other functions you'd be inclined to implement before this one?

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth - <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

*One byte saved thanks to @TheBikingViking.*

Straight up brute force.

```
f!sm*t.^dTQq1iQdQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21sm%2at.%5EdTQq1iQdQ&input=35&debug=0).

Comment: `f!smt` is one byte shorter.

Comment: @TheBikingViking oh, yeah thanks

Comment: Hurts my eyes, how the heck is this python..? Loved it nonetheless haha :)

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <del>59</del> 56 bytes

```
->x{a=1..x
a.detect{|k|a.all?{|y|x.gcd(y)>1||y**k%x<2}}}
```

Answer (score 5):

## J, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
[:*./@(5&p:%2^0=8&|)2^/@p:]
```

The Carmichael function is λ(*n*) and the totient function is φ(*n*).

Uses the definition where λ(*p*<sup>*k*</sup>) = φ(*p*<sup>*k*</sup>)/2 if *p* = 2 and *k* > 2 else φ(*p*<sup>*k*</sup>). Then, for general *n* = *p*<sub>1</sub><sup>*k*<sub>1</sub></sup> *p*<sub>2</sub><sup>*k*<sub>2</sub></sup> ⋯ *p*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>*k*<sub>*i*</sub></sup>, λ(*n*) = LCM[ λ(*p*<sub>1</sub><sup>*k*<sub>1</sub></sup>) λ(*p*<sub>2</sub><sup>*k*<sub>2</sub></sup>) ⋯ λ(*p*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>*k*<sub>*i*</sub></sup>) ].

### Usage

Extra commands used to format multiple input/output.

```
   f =: [:*./@(5&p:%2^0=8&|)2^/@p:]
   f 530
52
   (,.f"0) 1 2 3 10 35 101 530 3010 6511 10000
    1    1
    2    1
    3    2
   10    4
   35   12
  101  100
  530   52
 3010   84
 6511 3056
10000  500
```

### Explanation

```
[:*./@(5&p:%2^0=8&|)2^/@p:]  Input: integer n
                          ]  Identity function, get n
                    2   p:   Get a table of prime/exponent values for n
                     ^/@     Raise each prime to its exponent to get the prime powers of n
[:    (            )         Operate on the prime powers
                8&|            Take each modulo 8
              0=               Test if its equal to 0, 1 if true else 0
            2^                 Raise 2 to the power of each
       5&p:                    Apply the totient function to each prime power
           %                   Divide it by the powers of 2
  *./@                       Reduce using LCM and return
```

Comment: This gives the wrong answer for 10000 (1000 instead of the correct 500), and indeed for every multiple of 8. 2 is a peculiar prime, and λ(2^a) = 2^{a-2} (not 2^{a-1}) when a≥3.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, seems I can't even read my own output

Comment: you're not alone sometimes.... :)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>143</s> 135 bytes

*Edit: saved 8 bytes thanks to Neil*

An implementation using functional programming.

```js
n=>(A=[...Array(n).keys()]).find(k=>k&&!c.some(c=>A.slice(0,k).reduce(y=>y*c%n,1)-1),c=A.filter(x=>(g=(x,y)=>x?g(y%x,x):y)(x,n)==1))||1
```

#### Ungolfed and commented

```
n =>                                          // Given a positive integer n:
  (A = [...Array(n).keys()])                  // Build A = [0 ... n-1].
  .find(k =>                                  // Try to find k in [1 ... n-1] such as
    k && !c.some(c =>                         // for each coprime c: c^k ≡ 1 (mod n).
      A.slice(0, k).reduce(y =>               // We use reduce() to compute
        y * c % n, 1                          // c^k mod n.
      ) - 1                                   // Compare it with 1.
    ),                                        // The list of coprimes is precomputed
    c = A.filter(x =>                         // before the find() loop is executed:
      (                                       // for each x in [0 ... n-1], keep
        g = (x, y) => x ? g(y % x, x) : y     // only integers that verify:
      )(x, n) == 1                            // gcd(x, n) = 1
    )                                         // (computed recursively)
  ) || 1                                      // Default result is 1 (for n = 1)
```

#### Demo

Although it does work for `6511` and `10000`, I won't include them here as it tends to be a bit slow.

```js
let f =
n=>(A=[...Array(n).keys()]).find(k=>k&&!c.some(c=>A.slice(0,k).reduce(y=>y*c%n,1)-1),c=A.filter(x=>(g=(x,y)=>x?g(y%x,x):y)(x,n)==1))||1

console.log(f(1));     // 1
console.log(f(2));     // 1
console.log(f(3));     // 2
console.log(f(10));    // 4
console.log(f(35));    // 12
console.log(f(101));   // 100
console.log(f(530));   // 52
console.log(f(3010));  // 84
```

Comment: JS can do `0..n-1` ranges quite easily: `[...Array(n).keys()]`. This requires not one but two special cases but I'm still ahead: `n=>(a=[...Array(n).keys()]).find(k=>k&&!c.some(c=>a.slice(0,k).reduce(y=>y*c%n,1)-1),c=a.filter(x=>(g=(x,y)=>x?g(y%x,x):y)(x,n)==1))||1`

Answer (score 4):

## Actually, <s>30</s> <s>28</s> <s>25</s> <s>19</s> 26 bytes

The Carmichael function, `λ(n)` where `n = p_0**k_0 * p_1**k_1 * ... * p_a**k_a`, is defined as the least common multiple (LCM) of `λ(p_i**k_i)` for the maximal prime powers `p_i**k_i` that divide into `n`. Given that for every prime power except where the prime is `2`, the Carmichael function is equivalent to the Euler totient function, `λ(n) == φ(n)`, we use `φ(n)` instead. For the special case of `2**k` where `k ≥ 3`, we just check if `2**3 = 8` divides into `n` at the beginning of the program, and divide by 2 if it does.

Unfortunately, Actually doesn't currently have an LCM builtin, so I made a brute-force LCM. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OzcmWXVAXHdgaeKBv-KWkmBN4pWXMmDilZxA4pmAJc6jWWDilZNO&input=NDAzMjA)

```
;7&Yu@\w`iⁿ▒`M╗2`╜@♀%ΣY`╓N
```

**Ungolfing**

```
         Implicit input n.
;        Duplicate n.
7&       n&7 == n%8.
Yu       Logical NOT and increment. If n%8 == 0, return 2. Else, return 1.
@\       Integer divide n by 2 if n%8==0, by 1 otherwise.
          Thus, we have dealt with the special case where p_i == 2 and e_i >= 3.
w        Full prime factorization of n as a list of [prime, exponent] lists.
`...`M   Map the following function over the prime factorization.
  i        Flatten the array, pushing exponent, then prime to the stack.
  ⁿ▒       totient(pow(prime, exponent)).
╗        Save that list of totients in register 0.
2`...`╓  Get the first two values of n where the following function f(n) is truthy.
         Those two numbers will be 0 and our LCM.
  ╜@       Push the list in register 0 and swap with our n.
  ♀%       Get n mod (every number in the list)
  Σ        Sum the modulos. This sum will be 0, if and only if this number is 0 or LCM.
  Y        Logical NOT, so that we only get a truthy if the sum of modulos is 0.
N        Grab the second number, our LCM. Implicit return.
```

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how you did this in only 19 bytes.

Comment: @TheBitByte With use of the `totient` and `gcd` builtins. This would be shorter if Actually had `lcm` directly, but I don't mind it that much and that would only knock off 4 bytes at most, anyway.

Comment: The assertion that lcm(*a) = product(*a)/gcd(*a) is true when *a is a list of exactly two numbers; however, it is false in general for longer lists (example: if *a is {6,10,15}, it gives 900 instead of the correct answer of 60). [For that matter, it's wrong is *a is a list of one number as well!] And you can check that you get the wrong answer for over half the test cases listed in the OP.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>101</s> <s>86</s> <s>91</s> 90 bytes

A Ruby port of [my Actually answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93779/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome.

**Edit:** -4 bytes from removing `a` but +9 bytes from fixing a bug where `1` returned `nil`. -1 byte thanks to Cyoce.

```ruby
require'prime'
->n{((n%8<1?n/2:n).prime_division<<[2,1]).map{|x,y|x**~-y*~-x}.reduce :lcm}
```

**Ungolfing**

```ruby
require 'prime'
def carmichael(n)
  if n%8 < 1
    n /= 2
  end
  a = []
  n.prime_division.do each |x,y|
    a << x**(y-1)*(x-1)
  end
  return a.reduce :lcm
end
```

Comment: You don't need `a=`. Unfortunately, you return `nil` for n = 1 :(. `(n.prime_division<<[2,1])` fixes that. Not sure if there's a golfier way.

Comment: `(n%8<1?n/2:n).prime_division...` saves another 2 bytes.

Comment: @m-chrzan `a` is a remnant of an earlier golfing attempt. Thanks for the reminder about `a` and for heads up on `1`.

Comment: You can save a byte by using `.reduce :lcm` instead of `.reduce(:lcm)`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES 2016) 149

Python reference implementation ported to JS. Some fancy Pyhton builtin is missing in js, like `gcd` and `pow`, and the array comprehension is not standard in ES 6. This works in Firefox.

```js
n=>eval('for(g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a,p=(a,b,c)=>eval("for(r=1;b--;)r=r*a%c"),c=[for(_ of Array(i=n))if(g(i--,n)<2)i+1],k=1;c.some(x=>p(x,k,n)-1);)++k')
```

*Less golfed*

```js
n=>{
  g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a
  p=(a,b,c)=>{ 
    for(r=1;b--;)
      r=r*a%c
    return r
  }
  c=[for(_ of Array(i=n)) if(g(i--,n)<2) i+1]
  for(k=1;c.some(x=>p(x,k,n)-1);)
    ++k
  return k
}
```

Comment: recursive modpow is shorter: `p=(a,b,c)=>b?a*p(a,b-1,c)%c:1;`

Answer (score 1):

## Java8 <s>38</s> 19 + <s>287</s> <s>295</s> <s>253</s> <s>248</s> 241 = <s>325</s> <s>333</s> <s>272</s> <s>267</s> 260 bytes

```
BigInteger B(int i){return new BigInteger(""+i);}int c(int...k){int n=k[0];for(k[0]=1;n>1&!java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,n).filter(i->B(n).gcd(B(i)).equals(B(1))).allMatch(x->B(x).modPow(B(k[0]),B(n)).equals(B(1)));k[0]++);return k[0];}
```

**Imports, 19 bytes**

```
import java.math.*;
```

**Explanation**

It is a straight forward implementation. The co-primes are calculated in the `Set p` and every one's kth power is used to check if it equals 1 modulo n.

I had to use `BigInteger` because of precision issues.

**Usage**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Carmichael c = new Carmichael();
    System.out.println(c.c(3)); // prints 2
}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
// returns the BigInteger representation of the given interger
BigInteger B(int i) {
    return new BigInteger(""+i);
}
// for a given integer it returns the result of the carmichael function again as interger
// so the return value cannot be larger
int c(int... k) {
    int n = k[0];
    // iterate k[0] until for all co-primes this is true: (x^n) mod n == 1, if n==1 skip the loop
    for (k[0]=1;n > 1 && !java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, n)
                .filter(i -> B(n).gcd(B(i)).equals(B(1)))
                .allMatch(x -> B((int) x).modPow(B(k[0]), B(n)).equals(B(1)));k[0]++);
    return k[0];
}
```

Any suggestions to golf it more are welcome :-)

**Update**

- No elements outside the functions that keep the state
- Followed Olivier Grégoire's advice and saved 1 byte from `B()`
- Removed the `k()` method and `p` (co-primes) Set.
- Removed not required casting to int.
- Added varags and use for instead of while.

Comment: Can you have an ungolfed version (with linebreaks, comments here & there, etc.)

Comment: @OldBunny2800: Yeah, sure. However, I'll do it later today because now I am busy!

Comment: @OldBunny2800: I added an ungolfed version :-)

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure if this counts as it's neither a function nor a program. If it's a function, there are elements outside of it that keep the state, making it a de facto method (function is pure input->output without external state), if it's a program, the whole main method is missing. If my interpretations are incorrect, please tell me so! I think it's better to include `k(int)` in the loop as it's a one-liner and can be done. Plus, the constant O can be put in the `c` method as well. I guess you'll win bytes by doing so!

Comment: Concretely, `while(n>1&&!p.stream().allMatch(x->B((int)x).modPow(B(k), B(n)).equals(O)))` shaves bytes *and* fixes the issues I mentioned if you put the set and the constant back into the method. Also, you use `O` twice, replace by `B(1)` to shave bytes.

Comment: `return new BigInteger(""+i);` is shorter by one byte.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: Hey, thanks for the comments. I moved the "state" inside the methods. I don't think that `while(n>1&&!p.stream().allMatch(x->B((int)x).modPow(B(k), B(n)).equals(O)))` works as `k` variable has to be final. I am not sure that this can't be done in less code. I'll look into it with the first opportunity!

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry for that. `k` should be final, which is hard to do without putting it out (best case would be to write `final int K = k;` somewhere, hard given it's a parameter of a function, in the condition of a loop). Despite that, I totally disliked your answer because it was basically the initial algorithm, written in Java, and I was sure that we could do better in Java. So I answered it myself with another algorithm, much more "golfable", but much less efficient in terms of computer speed. I disliked, but +1'd still because you've made some pretty good work!

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <del>209</del> <del>207</del> <del>202</del> <del>194</del> 192 bytes

Code (96 bytes):

```
n->{for(int x,k=1,a;;k++){for(a=1,x=0;++x<=n&&a<2;)a=g(x,n)<2?p(x,k,n):1;if(a<2||n<2)return k;}}
```

extra functions (96 bytes):

```
int g(int a,int b){return b<1?a:g(b,a%b);}int p(int n,int p,int m){return p<2?n:n*p(n,p-1,m)%m;}
```

### Testing & ungolfed

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public class Main2 {

  static int g(int a,int b) { // recursive gcd
    return b < 1
        ? a
        : g(b,a%b);
  }

  static int p(int n, int p, int m) { // recursive modpow
    return p < 2
      ? n
      : n * p(n, p - 1, m) % m;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntUnaryOperator f = n -> {
      for(int x,k=1,a;;k++) { // for each k
        for(a=1,x=0;++x<=n&&a<2;) // for each x
          a=g(x,n)<2?p(x,k,n):1; // compute modpow(x,k,n) if g(x,n)
        if(a<2||n<2) // if all modpow(x,k,n)=1. Also check for weird result for n=1.
          return k;
      }
    };

    Arrays.stream(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 10, 35, 101, 530, 3010, 6511, 10000})
        .map(f)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

### Notes

- the use of `a` being an `int` is shorter than if I had to use a `boolean` to perform my tests.
- Yes, it's shorter to `valueOf` all new `BigInteger` than create a separate function (there are 5, plus the `ONE` constant is a freebie).
- Algorithm is different than @Master_ex' algorithm, so it's not just a golfed repost. Also, this algorithm is much less efficient as `gcd` is computed again and again for the same values.

### Shaves

1. 209 -> 207 bytes:

   - `if(...)a=...;` -> `a=...?...:1;`
   - `a==1` -> `a<2`
2. 207 -> 202 bytes

   - Got rid of `BigInteger` by golfing `gcd` and `modPow` for `int`.
3. 202 -> 194 bytes

   - looping `modPow` -> recursive
4. 194 -> 192 bytes

   - `==1` -> `<2` (seems to work for all the test cases, don't know for other numbers.)

Comment: Hey! I've noticed that the output is not the expected. See the question for the expected results. Personally, I often write unit tests before starting golfing my code, it helps! I guess that the problem could be the modPow on integers, I had also this problem and that's why I used BigInteger at the end.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm surprised, I let my tests run at every change. I'll check what's wrong.

Comment: @Master_ex I fixed it. Going back to the previous version is ok.

Comment: I find your recursive modpow method `p` pretty clever. I tried to use only integers at first too, but as I've mentioned in my answer, I had precision issues and that's why I've moved to `BigInteger` (i.e. `Math.pow(3, 100)%101` returned `60.0` instead of `1`). Your implementation is immune to this because it performs the mod in each iteration. However, it still suffers from a bug. For large `m` `p` may still return wrong results. Also, because of the recursion, `StackOverflowError` may easily occur for large input with the default stack size.

Comment: @Master_ex Yes, that's a consequence of the restriction to `int` types. I could use longs instead of ints, that'd be 8 extra bytes. But in my view, all the test cases are valid so I leave it like that. `StackOverflowError` can happen, but that's how recursive works. Methods exist to limit to 32 stacks, but these use many many more bytes. This implementation is fragile, yes, you are totally right. But it's strong enough for the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>208 200 149 144 140</s> 134 bytes

```
[](int n){int k=1,x,a,b,t,d=1;for(;d;)for(d=x=0;++x<n;d=a<2&t>1?k++:d){for(a=x,b=n;t=b;a=t)b=a%b;for(t=1,b=k;b--;t=t*x%n);}return k;};
```

A port of my [C implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94142/52904).

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/W89903)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>165 163 158 152</s> 143 bytes

```
int l(int n){int k=1,x,a,b,t,d=1;for(;d>0;)for(d=x=0;++x<n;d=a<2&t>1?k++:d){for(a=x,b=n;b>0;b=a%b,a=t)t=b;for(t=b=1;b++<=k;t=t*x%n);}return k;}
```

Another port of my [C implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94142/52904).

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/tWmaPZ)

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>278 276 272 265 256 243 140 134</s> 125 bytes

```cpp
k,x,a,b,t,d;l(n){for(k=d=1;d;)for(d=x=0;++x<n;d=a<2&t>1?k++:d){for(a=x,b=n;t=b;a=t)b=a%b;for(t=1,b=k;b--;t=t*x%n);}return k;}
```

This uses a slow modular exponentiation algorithm, computes the GCD too often and no longer leaks memory!

Ungolfed:

```
int gcd( int a, int b ) {
  int t;
  while( b ) {
    t = b;
    b = a%b;
    a = t;
  }
  return a;
}
int pw(int a,int b,int c){
  int t=1;
  for( int e=0; e<b; e++ ) {
    t=(t*a)%c;
  }
  return t;
}
int carmichael(int n) {
  int k = 1;
  for( ;; ) {
    int done = 1;
    for( int x=1; x<n; x++ ) {
      if( gcd(x,n)==1 && pw(x,k,n) != 1 ) {
        done = 0;
        k++;
      }
    }
    if( done ) break;
  }
  return k;
}
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/lm9KsO)

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 218 bytes

```
(λ(n)(let((fl #f)(cl(for/list((i n) #:when(coprime? n i))i)))(for/sum((k(range 1 n))#:break fl)(set! fl #t)
(for((i(length cl))#:break(not fl))(when(not(= 1(modulo(expt(list-ref cl i)k)n)))(set! fl #f)))(if fl k 0))))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
(require math)
(define f
  (λ(n)
    (let ((fl #f)
          (cl (for/list ((i n) #:when (coprime? n i))
                i)))
             (for/sum ((k (range 1 n)) #:break fl)
               (set! fl #t)
               (for ((i (length cl)) #:break (not fl))
                 (when (not (= 1 (modulo (expt (list-ref cl i) k) n)))
                   (set! fl #f)))
               (if fl k 0)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 2) 
(f 3)
(f 10)
(f 35)
(f 101)
(f 530)
(f 3010)
(f 6511)
(f 10000)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
12
100
52
84
3056
500
```

Answer (score 0):

**Axiom 129 bytes**

```
c(n)==(r:=[x for x in 1..n|gcd(x,n)=1];(v,k):=(1,1);repeat(for a in r repeat(v:=powmod(a,k,n);v~=1=>break);v<=1=>break;k:=k+1);k)
```

less golfed

```
cml(n)==
 r:=[x for x in 1..n|gcd(x,n)=1];(v,k):=(1,1)
 repeat 
   for a in r repeat(v:=powmod(a,k,n);v~=1=>break)
   v<=1=>break
   k:=k+1
 k
```

results

```
(3) -> [i,c(i)] for i in [1,2,3,10,35,101,530,3010,6511,10000]
   Compiling function c with type PositiveInteger -> PositiveInteger

   (3)
   [[1,1], [2,1], [3,2], [10,4], [35,12], [101,100], [530,52], [3010,84],
    [6511,3056], [10000,500]]
                                             Type: Tuple List PositiveInteger
```